# Packaging or Seeding SQLite3 DB with Electron Production App?

Tags: sqlite, electron, electron-builder

I have a sqlite3 database that I need to create in the `userData` directory (/Applications/Application Support/) when an application is installed.  The crux of my issue is that I need that database to have a bunch of data already when the user starts up the application for the first time.

How do I go about either seeding the database during the installation process (I assume a `postinstall` step) or having the sqlite3 database file be compiled into the build for the application?

More than happy to share any necessary code snippets. I don't know what is helpful off the bat.  Thanks!

I have already tried running the electron build process with the database in the src directory, but that doesn't make the file get compiled into the source code.

Comment: Managed to finally happen upon the information needed to get this to work: https://github.com/saltyshiomix/nextron/issues/175#issuecomment-1030649353

Hope this helps someone else as well!